# How to reinstall ffmpeg clean on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: ffmpeg, ubuntu-14.04, reinstall

sorry - might be a bit of a Newbie question, but after researching via Google I am even more confused.

I have Jon Severinsson's ffmpeg PPA installed on Ubuntu 14.04 and want to replace it with mc4man's PPA.
How do I purge the old PPA correctly and clean, so I can get the new one?

Is it

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:jon-severinsson/ffmpeg
```

and then

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mc3man/trusty-media
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

To be on safe side I removed ffmpeg completely before:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove ffmpeg
sudo apt-get --purge autoremove

sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:jon-severinsson/ffmpeg

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mc3man/trusty-media
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
```

I am not expert so maybe there is safer/better way but this worked for me. Interestingly last ffmpeg version from jon-severinsson was `ffmpeg version 1.2.6-7:1.2.6-1~trusty1 Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers` and in mc3man repo 
`ffmpeg version 2.6.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers`.

Comment: PPA to be removed: jon-severinsson ffmpeg
Warning:  Could not find package list for PPA: jon-severinsson ffmpeg

Comment: @曹博堯 That's fine.  Those lines are just there to remove an former version of ffmpeg that you haven't downloaded.

Comment: Thanks man it helped, I was getting sudo: add-apt-repository: command not found error fixed it from https://backlinkos.blogspot.com/2017/05/how-to-solve-sudo-add-apt-repository.html just adding "apt-get install software-properties-common"

Answer (score 4):

Today I found another PPA providing Jon Severinsson's ffmpeg package: https://launchpad.net/~fnu/+archive/ubuntu/main-fnu. Unlike the *mc3man/trusty-media* PPA it provides `ffmpeg version 1.2.6-7:1.2.6-1~trusty1`. It seems to be the same package contained in the old *jon-severinsson/ffmpeg* PPA.

Comment: You can also use this package I created : https://github.com/razzbee/ffmpeg_installer , it works just fine